# How to use the Fluent UI Northstar Color Palette?

Tags: typescript, colors, fluentui-react

Fluent UI Northstar comes with a color palette. I can find the [color names and gradients](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.52.0/color-palette) in the documentation, but how am I supposed to use the names and gradient values (100, 200, etc.) in TypeScript? I couldn't find any documentation or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more generic example how to use theme. On the global level you have to load and provide theme.

```
import { Provider, teamsTheme } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { Grid } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";

const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Provider theme={teamsTheme}>
      <Grid
        columns="minmax(50px, 0.75fr) 1fr 1fr 1fr"
        rows="50px 1fr"
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        {children}
      </Grid>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Then by component :

```
const Header: React.FC<SegmentProps> = ({children}) => {
  const styledHeaderWrapper = useCSS((theme) => ({
    gridColumn: "span 4",
    backgroundColor: theme.siteVariables.colorScheme.brand.white,
  }));
return (
    <Flex
      gap="gap.small"
      hAlign="center"
      vAlign="center"
      className={styledHeaderWrapper}
    >
      {children}
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: I must still be missing something. I found the useCSS import, however siteVariables only bring up fontSizes, not any other property.
interface SiteVariablesPrepared extends SiteVariablesInput {fontSizes: Record<string, string>}

Comment: Are You importing theme properly and providing this theme in your component three ?

Comment: Probably not :-) and I don't really know where to start. I didn't even know about useCSS before you posted the sample code. Would you have a link to the documentation, or maybe a CodeSandbox working demo?

Comment: https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.52.0/theming-examples

Answer (score 2):

Hi below You have an example for header component:

```
const Header: React.FC<SegmentProps> = () => {
  const styledHeaderWrapper = useCSS((theme) => ({
    gridColumn: "span 4",
    backgroundColor: theme.siteVariables.colorScheme.brand.background1,
  }));

  return (
    <Flex
      gap="gap.small"
      hAlign="center"
      vAlign="center"
      className={styledHeaderWrapper}
    >
      <Image src="LOGO.svg" />
      <Breadcrumb content="main/site1" />
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Input
          icon={<SearchIcon />}
          placeholder="Search..."
          iconPosition="start"
          fluid
          style={{ padding: "0 25%" }}
        />
      </div>
      <HeaderNavigationBar />
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Would you have a more general reference? I am trying to work with the built-in Northstar themes such as teamsTheme, not necessarily building a theme from scratch. teamsTheme.siteVariables doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: you should use theme northstar is reading current theme from context